# Web scraping DIV class in VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm having some trouble programming a VBA code to scrape div class data off a site and drop into excel. I cannot post the URL due to privacy concerns (patient data) but the code is posted below:

```
<div id="location-1" class="Location">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="info">
            <div class="column">
              <div class="element-1">[text]</div>
              <div class="element-2">[text]</div>
              <p class="element-3"></p>
              <p class="element-4">[text]</p>
              <p class="element-5"></p>
              <p class="element-6">[text]</p>
              <div class="dir">
                    <a href="[link]" class="dir" target="_blank">Get dir</a>
                  </div> 
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My code is posted below. I am trying to scrape the info from "Element-1" and "Element-2" into 1 row for each source. Any help here would be much appreciated!

```
Sub webscrape()
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As New HTMLdocument
    Dim source As Object
    
    With http
    .Open "get", "[link]", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    For Each source In html.getElementsByClassName("column")
    x = x + 1: Cells(x, 1) = source.getAttribute("element-1")
    Cells(x, 2) = source.getAttribute("element-2")
    Next source
    
End Sub
```

Comment: That is not how you can get the class attribute in vba. Try `source.className` instead of `source.getAttribute("element-1")`.

Comment: I thought you are trying to parse the classnames, as in `element-1`, `element-2` e.t.c and that is what my earlier suggestion about.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different solutions. (Not tested)

**The first one:**

```
Sub webscrape()
  Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
  Dim html As New HTMLdocument
  Dim nodeColumnElements As Object
  Dim currentRow As Long
  
  currentRow = x 'Here your start row
  
  With http
    .Open "get", "[link]", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
  End With
  
  Set nodeColumnElements = html.getElementsByClassName("column")(0).getElementsByTagName("div")
  Cells(currentRow, 1) = Trim(nodeColumnElements(0).innertext)
  currentRow = currentRow + 1
  Cells(currentRow, 2) = Trim(nodeColumnElements(1).innertext)
End Sub
```

**The second one grabs both elements directly:**

```
Sub webscrape()
  Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
  Dim html As New HTMLdocument
  Dim currentRow As Long
  
  currentRow = x 'Here your start row
  
  With http
    .Open "get", "[link]", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
  End With
  
  Cells(currentRow, 1) = Trim(html.getElementsByClassName("element-1")(0).innertext)
  currentRow = currentRow + 1
  Cells(currentRow, 2) = Trim(html.getElementsByClassName("element-2")(0).innertext)
End Sub
```