# Web scraping fields from DIV class, VBA errors

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to make an excel table of data from a website, i found this
[helpful example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64980493/web-scraping-div-class-in-vba#new-answer?newreg=3f8626ad29fd4c56ad13252f780dd574) however I get a VBA error.

My code is:

```
Sub WebData()
  Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
  Dim html As New HTMLdocument
  Dim currentRow As Long
  
  currentRow = x 'Here your start row
  
  With http
    .Open "get", "https://www.careinspectorate.com/index.php/care-services?detail=CS2004081195", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
  End With
  
  Cells(currentRow, 1) = Trim(html.getElementsByClassName("service_manager")(0).innertext)
  currentRow = currentRow + 1
  Cells(currentRow, 2) = Trim(html.getElementsByClassName("service_tel")(0).innertext)
End Sub
```

and I get the error " Run-time error '91' Object variable or with block variable not set. "
I have added MS HTML and XML v6.0 references to the project.

Once I get the basic import working, i will add more fields and then run this script on a list of "CS...." numbers.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `service_manager` is an id, not a class name: try `Trim(html.getElementById("service_manager").innertext)`

Comment: ...having said that it looks like the content you want is loaded dynamically *after* the page has loaded.  That will not happen using this approach - you'll need to use browser automation  - IE11 (if supported) or something like Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim Williams said in the comment, the content is loaded dynamically so you will not be able to extract it from the HTML document using XMLHTTP.

So what you can do instead is get the content from the XHR directly - From inspecting the website using DevTools, the XHR request for the service details is from `https://www.careinspectorate.com/templates/care-inspectorate/Apache/service_detail.php` with the request body `service_number='CS2004081195'` so that's what you need to replicate in your code.

Generally the result can be in any form (HTML,JSON,XML..etc) but in this case, I assume it came back as a `~` delimited text:

```
2004-11-16 00:00:00~Perth & Kinross Council - Adults with Learning Disabilities~Support services - care at home and housing support service combined~41d St Catherines Road~~~~Perth~PH1 5SJ~01738 477 637~~Shona Thompson~~~0~SP2003003370~Perth & Kinross Council~Active~56.399466738077300,-3.440588000000000~PH1 5SJ~Support Service~1
```

Since it's just a string, there are many ways to parse the data and I chose to split them into array and then retrieve the data by its index.

Full code below, this will get the manager's name and the telephone but obviously as this is an assumption, you will need to do multiple tests to confirm that this approach works:

```
Sub WebData()
  Const serviceNo As String = "CS2004081195"
  Const managerName As Long = 11
  Const managerTel As Long = 9
  
  Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
  Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
  
  Dim requestData As String
  requestData = "service_number='" & serviceNo & "'"
  
  With http
    .Open "POST", "https://www.careinspectorate.com/templates/care-inspectorate/Apache/service_detail.php", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    .send (requestData)
            
    Dim responseData As String
    responseData = .responseText
  End With
  
  Dim responseArr As Variant
  responseArr = Split(responseData, "~")
  
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change the name to the correct worksheet name
  
  Dim currentRow As Long
  currentRow = 2 'Here your start row
  
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 1) = Trim$(responseArr(managerName)) 'Always fully qualify your range or VBA will assume you are referring to the ActiveSheet which might not be what you want.
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 2) = Trim$(responseArr(managerTel))
  currentRow = currentRow + 1
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming that this is working, you will need to run this on a CS number that has all the fields you need then cross reference the array to the data to find out the index for the rest of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for your reply, thats excellent!  I had not realised the data was coming in after the page loaded which explained the issues i had when trying to do this in HTML!

The VBA worked perferctly, i just pulled out all fields for ~12,000 lines using the following finished code.   Theres probably more efficient ways of programming the parts i added/changed but it works!

Row A had a list of the "serviceNo" and the macro ran through it all in a few minutes.

```
 Sub WebData()
    
  'Const serviceNo As String = "CS2007142325"

  Const Field0 As Long = 0
  Const Field1 As Long = 1
  Const Field2 As Long = 2
  Const Field3 As Long = 3
  Const Field4 As Long = 4
  Const Field5 As Long = 5
  Const Field6 As Long = 6
  Const Field7 As Long = 7
  Const Field8 As Long = 8
  Const Field9 As Long = 9
  Const Field10 As Long = 10
  Const Field11 As Long = 11
  Const Field12 As Long = 12
  Const Field13 As Long = 13
  Const Field14 As Long = 14
  Const Field15 As Long = 15
  Const Field16 As Long = 16
  Const Field17 As Long = 17
  Const Field18 As Long = 18
  Const Field19 As Long = 19
  Const Field20 As Long = 20
  Const Field21 As Long = 21
  Const Field22 As Long = 22
  Const Field23 As Long = 23
  
  Dim currentRow As Long
  currentRow = 2 'Here your start row
  
  Dim cell As Range
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            serviceNo = cell.Value
            
  
  Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
  Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
  
  Dim requestData As String
  requestData = "service_number='" & serviceNo & "'"
  
  With http
    .Open "POST", "https://www.careinspectorate.com/templates/care-inspectorate/Apache/service_detail.php", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    .send (requestData)
            
    Dim responseData As String
    responseData = .responseText
  End With
  
  Dim responseArr As Variant
  responseArr = Split(responseData, "~")
  
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change the name to the correct worksheet name
  
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 2) = Trim$((serviceNo))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 3) = Trim$(responseArr(Field0)) 'Always fully qualify your range or VBA will assume you are referring to the ActiveSheet which might not be what you want.
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 4) = Trim$(responseArr(Field1))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 5) = Trim$(responseArr(Field2))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 6) = Trim$(responseArr(Field3))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 7) = Trim$(responseArr(Field4))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 8) = Trim$(responseArr(Field5))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 9) = Trim$(responseArr(Field6))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 10) = Trim$(responseArr(Field7))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 11) = Trim$(responseArr(Field8))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 12) = Trim$(responseArr(Field9))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 13) = Trim$(responseArr(Field10))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 14) = Trim$(responseArr(Field11))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 15) = Trim$(responseArr(Field12))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 16) = Trim$(responseArr(Field13))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 17) = Trim$(responseArr(Field14))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 18) = Trim$(responseArr(Field15))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 19) = Trim$(responseArr(Field16))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 20) = Trim$(responseArr(Field17))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 21) = Trim$(responseArr(Field18))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 22) = Trim$(responseArr(Field19))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 23) = Trim$(responseArr(Field20))
  ws.Cells(currentRow, 24) = Trim$(responseArr(Field21))
  
  currentRow = currentRow + 1
  Next cell
  
  
End With
  
End Sub
```

Comment: `1)` I will move `Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` and its next line, and `Dim ws As Worksheet` and its next line to before the `For` loop, no point re-setting the object if you are going to reuse it in the loop. `2)` writing 23 cells each loop seems to be pretty inefficient and should be the main source of why your macro took so long, you can solve this by making a 2D array of the right size to `responseArr` and transfer the value over before writing to all 23 cells at once.

Comment: ... `3)` if you are not targeting for any specific data and just doing a mass dump as your code shows, there's no meaning in declaring constant (there's no meaning behind the naming of `Field0` `Field1` ...etc), you are better off just giving the value directly and remove the usage of constants